# Can i get all the indexes from a tree model

Tags: qt, qt5

I have a tree model and i want to get all indices as QModelIndexList from the model.

But i am not able to find any function in the tree model which returns all the indices in the model.

Do i have to manually iterate through the indices in the tree model to get all the indices ?

```
void  iterate(const QModelIndex & index, const QAbstractItemModel * model)
{
    if (index.isValid())
    {
        // Add to list
    }

    if (!model->hasChildren(index) || (index.flags() & Qt::ItemNeverHasChildren))
    {
        return;
    }
    auto rows = model->rowCount(index);
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
        iterate(model->index(i, 0, index), model);
}
```

Comment: *Do i have to manually iterate through the indices in the tree model to get all the indices ?*, yes

Comment: I am just curious, why do you need all the indexes?